# Ansible ec2_instance_facts

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a basic Ansible playbook creating an ec2 instance in aws, its working fine, i want to pick the public ip from the created instance to do furthers task on it, i am using the following section:

```
  - name: get-facts
    ec2_instance_facts:
      region: eu-west-1
      aws_access_key: xxxxxxxxx
      aws_secret_key: xxxxxxx
      filters:
        "tag:Name": docker-server
    register: ec2
  - debug:   var=ec2.instances
```

But i want to get just the ip address, according to the documentation public_ip
is a string, but i cannot call it when i use ec2.instances.public_ip i get error:
"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
what can i do to get the public ip for my created ec2 instance ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is `ec2.instances.public_ip_address` and `public_ip`

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_instance_info_module.html#return-instances/public_ip_address

---

`ec2_instance_facts` deprecated, ansible offer to use `ec2_instance_info` 
See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_instance_facts_module.html

---

**UPDATE:**

```
  - name: Print info
    debug: var="ec2.instances[0].public_ip_address"
  - name: Loop instances
    debug:
      var: item.public_ip_address
    with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,
okay its now like this:
```
 - name: get-facts
    ec2_instance_info:
      region: eu-west-1
      aws_access_key: xxxxxx
      aws_secret_key: xxxxxxx
      filters:
        "tag:Name": docker-server
       
  - debug:   var=ec2.instances.public_ip_address
```
and still getting:
```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2.instances.public_ip_address": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```
Any clue?

Comment: `ec2.instances` is an array. You can not read properties directly from a list. You need to access it by `indices` or do a loop over `instances`. Please check both use cases in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support and clarification, its finally worked like this:

```
- name: get-facts
    ec2_instance_info:
      region: xxxxx
      aws_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxx
      aws_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxx
      filters:
        "tag:Name": docker-server
    register: ec2
  - debug: var="ec2.instances[0].public_ip_address"
```